# Upon booting an Arch Linux installation media, how do I know which drive is which?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, arch-linux

So let's say I have a 5 disks. How do I know which one is `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lsblk` and `lsblk -f` to examine the disk sizes, partition tables, and their assigned names. Temporarily mount unrecognized partitions at `/mnt` or somewhere similar, to look inside.

```
$ lsblk -o name,type,size,fstype,label
NAME        TYPE   SIZE FSTYPE LABEL
sda         disk 596.2G        
├─sda1      part   100M vfat   EFI
├─sda2      part   100M        
├─sda3      part   200M ext4   rainboot
├─sda4      part  37.9G ext4   rainroot
├─sda5      part 491.9G ext4   rainhome
├─sda6      part  63.6G ntfs   raindows
├─sda7      part   450M ntfs   
└─sda8      part     2G swap   swap
sr0         rom  100.6M        
mmcblk0     disk   3.7G        
└─mmcblk0p1 part   3.7G ext4   keycard
```

Lsblk also can also show the manufacturer and model if you specify the right fields (and `-d` to omit partitions). `fdisk -l` is another way to get this information.

```
$ lsblk -d -o name,tran,vendor,model,serial
NAME    TRAN   VENDOR   MODEL                   SERIAL
sda     sata   ATA      Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB S3Z9NB0KA12345K
nvme0n1 nvme            KINGSTON SNVS1000G      50026B1234D5B512
```

Comment: Note `fstype` and `label` need extra privileges, so you will have to run as root. e.g. `sudo  lsblk -o name,type,size,fstype,label`

Comment: @richard: Normally they don't – unlike blkid, lsblk also uses the udev database, which is world-readable. If it lacks the fstype & label information, then your udev is broken.